# How can I add Ubuntu as an option to Windows Bootloader?

Tags: windows, bootloader

- Windows installed first on first SSD
- Ubuntu installed after on a separate SSD
- I have to enter the boot menu via F11 to be able to access Ubuntu. The option for Ubuntu does not appear on Windows Bootloader

What can I do to add Ubuntu to the Bootloader options?

Answer (score 0):

you should enter on your BIOS and check if the GRUB options is available to select as default load, if it's possible, select it, save and restart your pc. now u should be able to select your OS as u want to start with